# Advanced Find does not work for Notes in Outlook 2016

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2016

Advanced Find does not work for Notes in Outlook 2016.

No error message, no results.

How to fix?

Comment: Have you tried running a repair install of Office?

Comment: What happens? Does the find window open?

Comment: @freginold it behaves as if there is no sought content

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using it properly? Did you click Field, then navigate through "All Note Fields" to "Content"?

This is Advanced Find:

[image]

Searching using both the Advanced tab and the Notes tab, I'm able to get the right results.

Make sure none of the options in the More Choices tab are checked.

Comment: I sure I am using it properly, because sometimes it works.

Comment: so what happens if you try the Advanced tab? How many tries fail out of 10 or 15, for instance?